# Banshee not playing anything

Tags: sound, 14.10, banshee

I just installed Banshee on Kubuntu 14.10 and even though it can import all my music from my hard disk, it doesn't play anything, displaying a cross against each file I try to play. When I start it from a terminal, I see a plethora of errors which look like this

```
  at MusicBrainz.Query`1[MusicBrainz.Release].LoadResults () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

and

```
(Banshee:16294): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 2677 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

I googled up errors that look like this, but I couldn't find a solution that works for me. Also, banshee starts muted.

I should probably add here that Youtube, and pretty much anything else work fine.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Have you tried to install Ubuntu Restricted Extras and if so check the permissions of your harddrive (specially if you are using ntfs-3g)?

Comment: Thanks deus. 

Installing kubuntu-restricted-extras helped. Somehow it got uninstalled in a recent Ubuntu upgrade.

Comment: @leastaction: Please put this as an answer and select it as the right answer so that the issue can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Deus, doing the following helped:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-restricted-extras
```

The command most appropriate to your version of Ubuntu can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats). I am using Kubuntu 14.10 presently.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem where Banshee wouldn't play any of the music that was imported.

So, I decided to start it from the terminal to see what error messages I got.
I just typed "banshee" into the terminal.

Starting from the terminal solved the problem for me, so I suspect it has something to do with the commands or options when Banshee start from the menu.

I'm using Linux Mint 17.3.   I edited the options ("--redirect-log --device-activate=%u") that are entered when loading from the menu.  Problem solved.

I realize this isn't Ubuntu so I apologize if I shouldn't put this here.  I'll probably put Ubuntu on a second partition when I get my data backed up.

Answer (score 1):

Heemayl probably nailed it. The thing is certain software isn't part of GNU or open-source. Installing the "restricted" extras should solve it. As to why they're not included in distros (if you'll pardon the non-technical answer) is the same reason lawyers don't go to the beach. Cats keep trying to bury them :}